# Bilinear forms with polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's consider $V=\Bbb {R_1}[x]$ (the space of the polynomials of degree less than or equal to 1), with $B=\{1,x\}$ (the canonical basis). Let be $f:V \times V\rightarrow \Bbb {R} $ the function defined as follows on the elements of $B \times B$:

$f(1,1)=0$,

$f(x,x)=0$,

$f(1,x)=5$

$f(x,1)=-5$

Show that $f$ is multilinear and alternating, and that if $p(x)=p_0+p_1x$ and $q(x)=q_0+q_1(x)$ then $f(p(x),q(x))=5p_0q_1-5p_1q_0$.

Actually my biggest problem is to find the explicit form of the function $f$ starting from the base that they give me, also it costs me a little the handling of bilinear forms since I still train myself to demonstrate what they ask me, any help would be well received. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Consider the function $g:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ such that $f=g\circ\phi$, where $\phi:V\to\mathbb R^2$ is the isomorphism induced by $B$. That is, think about it in terms of coordinate tuples. What does $g$ look like in matrix form?

Comment: @amd Thanks for your idea!